# Detect the closing bracket belong to the open bracket when there is more than one open & close bracket inside the bracket

Tags: vb.net

Actually, I want to do this to detect the value inside the rounding bracket and do the rounding to whatever inside the rounding bracket. For example:

```
Dim h As String = "ROUNDING(30.98998(10))*2+3"    
Dim r As String = h.ToString.Substring(h.ToString.IndexOf("ROUNDING(") + 1, h.ToString.IndexOf(")") - 1 - h.ToString.IndexOf("ROUNDING("))
```

In this case, after the `ROUNDING(` there is one more `(` and `)`. How to make the open bracket on the `ROUNDING` to match to the end of it's closing bracket?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the following `ReadInBetweenSameDepth` `Function`.

```
Public Function ReadInBetweenSameDepth(str As String, delimiterStart As Char, delimiterEnd As Char) As String
    If delimiterStart = delimiterEnd OrElse String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(str) OrElse str.Length <= 2 Then
        Return Nothing
    End If
    Dim delimiterStartFound As Integer = 0
    Dim delimiterEndFound As Integer = 0
    Dim posStart As Integer = -1
    For i As Integer = 0 To str.Length - 1
        If str(i) = delimiterStart Then
            If i >= str.Length - 2 Then
                'delimiter start is found in any of the last two characters
                Return Nothing
            End If
            'it means, there isn't anything in between the two
            If delimiterStartFound = 0 Then
                'first time
                posStart = i + 1
            End If
            'assign the starting position only the first time...
                'increase the number of delimiter start count to get the same depth
            delimiterStartFound += 1
        End If
        If str(i) = delimiterEnd Then
            delimiterEndFound += 1
            If delimiterStartFound = delimiterEndFound AndAlso i - posStart > 0 Then
                Return str.Substring(posStart, i - posStart)
                'only successful if both delimiters are found in the same depth
            End If
        End If
    Next
    Return Nothing
End Function
```

It basically checks if the delimiters (such as `(` and `)` ) are in the same "depth".

Comment: I just did that with the help of a guy on stackoverflow in PHP using RegEx, so I tried to do it, but finally abandon the idea to yours and then saw you already posted it. Good function !

Comment: Thanks for the help hehe